# Finding decaying solution using shooting method

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-calculus

Consider the following simple model equation:
$$
\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=y-y^2,$$
which satisfies the decaying boundary condition
$$
\lim_{x\to \infty}y(x)=0,\quad \lim_{x\to \infty }y'(x)=0.$$
The solution to the above boundary value problem  is given by
$$
y(x)=\frac{3}{2}\text{sech}^2(\frac{x}{2}).$$
In particular, $y(0)=3/2$ and $y'(0)=0$.

Now I want to use the [shooting method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shooting_method) to find a good numerical approximation to the above solution. First, observe that the solution is an even function. Thus we have $y'(0)=0$ and we only need to guess $y_0$ with $y(0)=y_0$. Let $y(x,y_0)$ denote the function that solves the initial value problem
$$ \frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=y-y^2,\quad y(0)=y_0,\quad y'(0)=0.$$
My question is that for the decaying boundary condition, what is my target condition? Is it
$$
F(y_0):=|y(L,y_0)|+|y'(L,y_0)|=0$$
for sufficiently large $L$?

The following figure shows the $F(y_0)$ versus $y_0$ curve plotted by Mathematica when $L=10$. It seems that there is a singularity at $y_0=3/2$ such that the value of $F(y_0)$ is extremely large when $y_0$ passes through $3/2$. So I do not think that above target condition is a good one.
[[image: <span class=]$F(y_0)$ versus $y_0$ curve when $L=10$" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P0E08.png)

Comment: Mathematica can solve NDE's via the shooting method specifically, see for instance https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveBVP.html. The only problematic point I see with the previous link is that implementing the decaying condition as $y(T)=0$ runs into numerical issues when $L\gtrsim 6.5.$

Comment: Thank you very much for the link, though it does not seem to answer my question. Here the boundary conditions are imposed at infinity. I want to know  how to transform them into a computable target condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are moving towards a saddle point in phase space. The only way to reach it is via one of the branches of the stable manifold. As in the linearization at $y=0$ the quadratic term falls away, one is left with $y''=y$ which has as solution $y(x)=Ce^{-x}+De^x$. For the stable solution you need $D=0$. Every error, method related or floating point, will give a non-zero value to $D$ which leads to a solution rapidly growing away from the $x$-axis.

Thus the condition one should enforce at $x=L$ is $D=0$ or $$y(L)+y'(L)=0$$
in this first approximation. The equation can thus be solved as a boundary value problem with this condition and continued as $y(L)e^{L-x}$ for $x>L$.

Further, one can integrate the equation once, after multiplying with $2y'$,
$$
y'^2=y^2-\frac23y^3+C.
$$
For the desired solution this gives $C=0$ and thus either $y(0)=0$ or $y(0)=\frac32$. Along the solution to the saddle point, at every point one has thus the identity
$$
y'(x)+y(x)\sqrt{1-\frac23y(x)}=0.
$$
This gives the exact second boundary condition without using a perturbation or other approximation method.

Using the substitution $u=\sqrt{1-\frac23y(x)}\iff y=\frac32(u^2-1)$, $y'=3uu'$, this leads quickly to the exact solution.

Using these pieces to produce an improved shooting graph gives

```
f = lambda y,t: [y[1],y[0]*(1-y[0])]
v = np.linspace(0,1.6,201)
def shoot(v,L):
    y = odeint(f,[v,0],[0,L],atol=1e-12,rtol=1e-12,hmax=0.1)[-1]
    return y[1]+y[0]*abs(1-2/3*y[0])**0.5
for L in np.linspace(4,7,7): 
    plt.plot(v,[shoot(vv,L) for vv in v])
plt.grid(); plt.show()
```

As one can see, with increasing $L$ the sensitivity of the target value from the initial value grows rapidly, meaning the solutions reach the saddle point and escape along the unstable manifold. The velocity of the escape then gets increased by the non-linear term for larger $|y|$.

[image]

Comment: Then the first part still applies, use the linearization and perhaps some terms of a perturbation expansion to compute the stable manifold as "far-field solution". Derive from that the upper boundary condition and use a relatively small value for $L$ to connect the later part to the initial dynamic.

Comment: Actually, I am dealing with a more complex problem in which one cannot obtain the initial guess from the first integral. So I should use the target condition similar to $y'(L)+y(L)=0$ in this problem?

Comment: Okay, I got it. Thank you. One last question. What is a good choice for the numerical value of $L$ which we need to be relatively small? Can I take $L=5$?

Comment: Yes. Here it shifts the solution only minimally, like from 1.5 to 1.4999. You might want to use multiple shooting etc., but be aware that BVP solvers give sometimes bad initial values for IVP solvers. /// Yes, the $L=5$ curve looks regular enough for a scalar root-finder to work without problems. One has to test if $|y(L)|\ll 1$ is satisfied to some level of accuracy.